# Encrypt Email with Attachments using C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to send an email from the system that would be encrypted. when the certificate gets installed in the client machine the user will be able to read the contents of the email. if the certificate is not installed, the email content will not be shown.

Below is the code for the same

```
    X509Certificate2 SignCert = new X509Certificate2(SigningCertPath, "Password");

    X509Certificate2 EncryptCert = new X509Certificate2(EncryptingCertPath, "");

    Attachment attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment("C:/Files/Sample.docx");

    MailMessage Msg = new MailMessage();

    StringBuilder Message = new StringBuilder();

    Message.AppendLine("Content-Type: text/" + ((HTML) ? "html" : "plain") +

        "; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"");

    Message.AppendLine("Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit");

    Message.AppendLine();

    Message.AppendLine(Body);

    byte[] BodyBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Message.ToString());

    EnvelopedCms ECms = new EnvelopedCms(new ContentInfo(BodyBytes));

    CmsRecipient Recipient = new CmsRecipient(

        SubjectIdentifierType.IssuerAndSerialNumber, EncryptCert);

    ECms.Encrypt(Recipient);

    byte[] EncryptedBytes = ECms.Encode();


    MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream(EncryptedBytes);

    AlternateView av = new AlternateView(memStream,

        "application/pkcs7-mime; smime-type=signed-data;name=smime.p7m");

    Msg.AlternateViews.Add(av);


    SignedCms Cms = new SignedCms(new ContentInfo(EncryptedBytes));

    CmsSigner Signer = new CmsSigner

        (SubjectIdentifierType.IssuerAndSerialNumber, SignCert);


    Cms.ComputeSignature(Signer);

    byte[] SignedBytes = Cms.Encode();

    string smtp_from = "From Email Address";

    MailAddress fromAddress = new MailAddress(smtp_from, "From EmailAddress");

    Msg.From = fromAddress;

    Msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(To));

    Msg.Subject = Subject;

    //Msg.Attachments.Add(attachment);


    SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();

    string smtp_server = "smtpdetails";
    int smtp_port = 587;
    string smtp_username = "smtpusername";
    string smtp_password = "smtp_password";

    smtpClient.Host = smtp_server;
    smtpClient.Port = smtp_port;

    System.Net.NetworkCredential myCredentials =
    new System.Net.NetworkCredential(smtp_username, smtp_password);
    smtpClient.Credentials = myCredentials;

    smtpClient.Send(Msg);
```

The code is working fine without any issues and sends an encrypted email. However, when I tried to add an attachment to the code, the encryption logic is not working and I am getting an unencrypted email with the attachment.

I tried with the mimekit, however, it didn't work. Can anyone let me know what changes I need to do for my scenario? I don't want to encrypt the attachment. I just want to encrypt the email content and add an attachment to it.

Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Doesn't make sense to me. Why would you encrypt the body but not the attachment? And why do you care? If the recipient can decrypt the body, they can decrypt the attachment, too. Why would someone that's not allowed to read the body be allowed to have the attachment?

Comment: @Fildor It is because the attachments are password protected. Hence I am not encrypting them.

Comment: So you are willing to go out of your way and make it harder for you, because you rely on a rather crappy password protection, that you cannot even enforce to be in place for each attachment? - Bad idea in my book.

Comment: @Fildor This is based on the client requirement. They want the attachment to be password protected and not encrypted.

Comment: Don't you hate it when clients are too specific ...

Comment: @Fildor :)  They are the one's who is paying us.... So we need to accept what they say.. :)

Comment: If you are in the business for some time, you'll learn to "make them want something else" ;) - sometimes, at least. It's one thing to accept "weird" requirements. It's another to jump over a cliff and see it coming from miles away ...

Comment: @Fildor I have already showed them regarding encrypting the email as well as attachment. however they stick to their requirement. I have a working code that encrypts the email as well the attachment. but for them they don't need to encrypt the attachment.

Comment: I am tempted to say "just show them how you hack that password in 5 secs or less" ...